# Visual Studio 2017 NugetPackageManager not syncing with private repository

Tags: nuget, teamcity, visual-studio-2017

I have a TeamCity hosted Nuget package repository. I see the package in the repo xml, `http://teamcity.mycompany.com:8080/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/Packages(Id='MyCompany.MyPackage',Version='1.0.21')`

But when I look to reference the package in my visual studio project, it still says the previous version is the latest one. I attempt to click refresh, doesn't show the latest version. I confirmed the 1.0.21 is listed as absolute latest version by going directly to the package and checking the xml.

I have attempted to use the `report a problem` in the upper right of the IDE, but it's unresponsive. hopefully someone from Microsoft sees this.

Comment: found a workaround, but it is still an issue: 1) open nuget management panel in VS. 2) click browse tab 3) click the little refresh button to the right. 3) go to installed tab and click refresh there as well. newly updated version appears.

Comment: Thanks for your workaround. Please share your feedback link here. I will test this issue in my side and if I reproduce this issue, I will vote and add comments for your feedback.